# Android Emulator Displays Local Images but Not URI Images

Tags: android, maui

I'm working on a MAUI app with the Android emulator and having a problem with images displaying.  Images that are bundled with the application display fine.  However images that use a URI (https://whatever) are just blank - they don't display anything.  This is not an issue with connectivity because the browser works fine on the emulator.  What else could be stopping these images from web sites to display correctly?

Comment: have you checked the Android console output for any messages related to loading images?

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> `
outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Farid - I tried that, uninstalled, redeployed, but did not change things.  Jason, I've looked around and round the device log but not found anything yet.  Thank you both for the suggestions.

Comment: Could you open the url correctly in your browser  in the Android emulator?

Comment: Yes.  I had the same problem with the monkey images from the .NET MAUI Workshop at https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/dotnet-maui-workshop.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Actually I just downloaded the GA and it is now working.  So must have gotten fixed along the way.  Thank you for the suggestions.